# How to show a snackbar in a specific video time?

Tags: javascript

I tried using "if else" statements in javascript, but I can't make it work.

Here's the js script:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function getCurTime() { 
    alert(vid.currentTime);
} 
var vidTime = vid.currentTime;

if(vidTime = 11.725395) 
{
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar") 
  x.className = "show";
  setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you type one single `=` it means that you are assigning a value to a variable. But inside the if condition, you don't want to do that! You want to compare two values. To do this in JavaScript, type `==`.

```
if(vidTime == 11.725395) 
{
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar") 
  x.className = "show";
  setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: I just started coding, and I am still confused in javascript. But now, all I need is how to show that snackbar. It outputs me some error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that "show" class is defined in your css, and makes the element visible, and the element is not visible by default
2. Use **`==`** operator for comparison of values. **`=`** means "**assign** value to the variable on the **left**"
3. You can use `x.classList.add("show")` and `x.classList.remove("show")` in your example for increased readability - and by doing so you avoid deleting other classes that are already assigned to this element.
4. **Now the most important part.** Right now your code will run once. Are your sure your if statement will ever be **true**?. Use a **loop** to check for the video play time all the time **until** it hit values between 11-12 seconds, or other of your choice. (loop should also be ended if time exceeds 12 seconds - if the user plays video from ex. 45 second.

[Read here about iterations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Comment: Ok, i'm going to try it.